# Ubuntu Studio crashes on bootable usb

Tags: dual-boot, live-usb, ubuntu-studio

Till about 2 years ago, I was consistently using linux, experimenting with flavours and all. Till my old laptop finally decided to shut down for good. The new laptop I got is a Dell inspiron 5400 with i5 8th gen and Nvidia with Windows 10 pre-installed. With the newer BIOS security and all, a dual boot didn't work, and I had to recover my installation.
Then, I tried bootable usb drive. Here, after creating a bootable usb, and installing ubuntu on a usb drive, the first time I run, it asks for updates. After running updates, it asks for a restart, and then starts the problem. After restart, even if the usb drive is the first option for boot, it hangs. And does not boot.
Tried various tips and tricks, but didn't work.
Request for the more experienced for some help. Have stopped working on photo edits and audio recording due to this!!!

Comment: Please tell us which version of Ubuntu Studio that you are using. One way to tell us is the name of the iso file that you downloaded. Tell us also if you made an installed system (installed like into an internal drive, but in this case installed into a USB drive), or if you made a persistent live system. You can also run `lsb_release -a`. Please edit your original question to answer the questions and to show the output of the lsb_... command line.